# How do I use jira-python to update a JIRA version name?

Tags: python, jira

I've been using the jira-python `create_version` function, which is very useful.  However, I sometimes need to change a JIRA version name across dozens of projects and there doesn't seem to be an `update_version` function, unless I've totally missed it.

For example, let's say I have a JIRA release name "Columbia" in 25 JIRA projects and I want to change that JIRA release name to "Colorado".

Presumably, this would use the [Update Version JIRA rest API.](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/version-updateVersion)

Comment: If not familiar with this lib, but [source](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira) indicated that all exposed API is explicitly defined in `jira/client.py`. Unfortunately, there is no mention of `update_version` there (while there is a mention of `create_version`), so it looks like this functionality is not ready yet and project may benefit from submitting a pull request :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
version.update(name="May1", releaseDate="2020-05-01")
```